# i can't validate my form all at once also the validation is not working on one of form elements

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

1. i want to validate my inputs all at once
2. the element with name comment is submitted without any validation

the code is for validating everything in the form the last one is not even working name and email is working but comment is not and i can't figure why

also its validate on at time how can i validate them all at once when user click on submit?

javascript code:

```
<script >

  function Validate() {

    var username = document.forms['forrm1']['name'];
    var email1 = document.forms['forrm1']['email'];
    var comment1 = document.forms['forrm1']['comment'];

     if (username.value == ""){
            username.style.border = "1px solid red";
            document.getElementById('nameErr').innerHTML = "Username is required";
            document.getElementById('nameErr').style.color = "red";
            username.focus();
            return false;}

      else if (email1.value == ""){
            email1.style.border = "1px solid red";
            document.getElementById('emailErr').innerHTML = "email is required";
            document.getElementById('emailErr').style.color = "red";
            email1.focus();
            return false;}

     else if (comment1.value == ""){
            comment1.style.border = "1px solid red";
            document.getElementById('textareaErr').innerHTML = "comment is empty";
            document.getElementById('textareaErr').style.color = "red";
            comment1.focus();
            return false;}  
       }

   </script>
```

html form that i want to validate:

the comment element is submitted without any validation

```
 <form name="forrm1" method="post" action="add_comments.php" onsubmit="return Validate()" id="comment_form">
            <input type="hidden" name="target" value="sabapage.php"/>
            <div> Name <input type="text" name="name" id="name"> <span Id="nameErr"></span></div><br>

            Email <input type="Email" name="email" id="email"> <span id="emailErr"></span><br>

            Comment <br><textarea name="comment" id="comment"rows="5" cols="50" placeholder="type here ..." >
                        </textarea><span id="textareaErr"></span><br>

            <input type="submit" value="submit" >

    </form>
```

Comment: Are you calling your `Validate` function anywhere in your code? Also you're returning if all your cases.

Comment: so do not return from inside the if and do not use if else. You are really just reinventing `required` attribute and html5 validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Validating all inputs at once:

Because your validation code is in an if...else if structure, only the first invalid input will be highlighted as invalid. The other validations are then skipped due to the else statements.

To validate all the inputs at once, you should remove the 'else' keywords so each if statement can function independently.

Instead of doing this:

```
if (username.value == ""){
    /* code */}
else if (email1.value == ""){
    /* code */}
else if (comment1.value == ""){
    /* code */}
```

Do this:

```
if (username.value == ""){
    /* code */}
if (email1.value == ""){
    /* code */}
if (comment1.value == ""){
    /* code */}
```

2. Comment is submitted without validation:

The spaces between your <textarea> and </textarea> tags cause a string of spaces to be inserted into the text area element, so it's value is never null even if the user doesn't write anything, and it doesn't trigger the validation. Remove these spaces and it will work as expected.

Eg. instead of doing this:

```
<textarea>
      </textarea>
```

Do this:

```
<textarea>
</textarea>
```

Or do this:

```
<textarea></textarea>
```